# Database not working on the root of Wordpress theme

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have created my own table on my wordpress database and created the filter search form. Now, my problem is that, I dont know how to connect my database to my search filter form in wordpress.

Here is the process, I send the keyword from index.php to result.php, and it shows nothing, just a blank page.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
global $wpdb;
$destination = $_POST["destination"];

echo "Welcome test" . $destination;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM rates WHERE location = '" . $destination ."';";

echo $sql;
echo "search this";

foreach ( $wpdb->get_results($sql) as $result ) { 
 echo "search for". $result->location;
}                                  
?>
```

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks with that code as no attempt is made to validate the user submitted data and you don't use prepared statements

Comment: Yes, I am just new to connecting database WordPress and MySQL, can you suggest any best practices for avoiding SQL injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp-content/themes/Your-Theme-Name/result.php

```
<?php
    /*
     * Template Name: MyResultPage
    */

        /* You can also use require_once('wp-load.php'); */
        get_header(); 

        global $wpdb;
        $destination = $_POST["destination"];
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . "rates";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `". $table . "` WHERE location = '". $destination. "'" ; 

        $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

        foreach($result as $res) {
           echo "search for". $res->location;
        }

    ?>
```

Then, you create a new page in your wordpress admin and set the template to result.php template name: MyResultPage (for example).

[image]

Comment: Still nothing shows up, even added define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);  
require_once('wp-load.php'); . Still nothing shows up

Comment: Oh..wait, have you created a the page result.php as a template?

Comment: You need to create a new page in wordpress admin, and then set it to your template created page (result.php). then it will show up

Comment: Can you give me a details process on how to set my template as a new page?

Comment: well, unfortunately, it still shows a white blank page. :(

Answer (score 0):

you should either include wp-config.php file in the header of the file which will include all the relevant files in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you plz check below code and it output.

i added one page in root directory of WordPress and make one page and add this code.

**test.php**

```
<?php 
     define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);  
     require_once('wp-load.php');
     global $wpdb;
     $result = $wpdb->get_results(("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type = 'page'"), ARRAY_A);

     foreach( $result as $key => $val )
     {
        echo '<p>Title - '.$val['post_name'].'</p>';
        echo '<p>ID - '.$val['ID'].'</p>';
     }
?>
```

Now here is out put of this page it shows all page title and id.

**Output:**

```
<p>Title - sample-page</p>
<p>ID - 2</p>
<p>Title - sample-page1</p>
<p>ID - 3</p>
```